# Using powershell or cmd prompt to rename multiple files in multiple folder to the same name

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

i'm trying to get powershell or command promopt to help me rename 1 file (with a different name) which appears accross multiple folders and can't seem to make it work;

all the files that need to change are .TGA files, they are the only .TGA files that appear in their respective folders.
all the folders are under one parent folder and have different names based on the client, similarly the .TGA files all have different names too.

for example

```
Z:\ClientWork\Joe Bloggs\horizon.tga
Z:\ClientWork\Arnold Palmer\cheesey golf balls.tga
Z:\ClientWork\Biscuit Bob\bourbons.tga
Z:\ClientWork\Stanley Ipkiss\tribalmasks.tga
```

each client folder also contains other files which need to be unchanged, only the .tga files need to be altered and all of them need to be changed to the same name

for example

```
Z:\ClientWork\Joe Bloggs\bob.tga
Z:\ClientWork\Arnold Palmer\bob.tga
Z:\ClientWork\Biscuit Bob\bob.tga
Z:\ClientWork\Stanley Ipkiss\bob.tga
```

I'm aware of using wildcards like `*.tga` to tell the system to rename all tga files but i can't seem to make this work i9n the above scenario so hoping someone smarter will have an answer before i have to manually do this to 1000s of folders.

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of PowerShell code should do that :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\ClientWork -Recurse *.tga | Rename-Item -NewName "bob.tga"
```

Comment: Massive thanks for this! i was hugely overcomplicating it, this worked like a charm and everything has updated correctly, thanks